# Matching fields in a log file and transforming results

Tags: regex, perl

First a quick intro.  I'm new here, so if I screw up a post, please let me know and I'll fix it.

I've been trying to accomplish my goal using perl, but I'm stuck.  I don't need to use perl to accomplish it, but I figure it's that, or Excel and I like perl better.  If you have a better method please share.

I start with a file (output from a log file). It is 1 line, fields delimitted by colon.  Here is an example of the file:

```
RmDenySumm:SGID=46244:Req=15000:tsid=46244:AllocBw=38332:BwList=12456/12500/3750/5876/3750:tsid=63042:AllocBw=38750:BwList=15000/12500/3750/3750/3750:tsid=63043:AllocBw=36717:BwList=14706/12500/3750/5761:tsid=63044:AllocBw=37011:BwList=15000/12500/5761/3750:tsid=61741:AllocBw=38450:BwList=12339/3750/6501/12502/3357:tsid=61721:AllocBw=37460:BwList=12500/15000/4200/5760:tsid=2072:AllocBw=31975:BwList=12136/12339/3750/3750:tsid=2073:AllocBw=24260:BwList=14634/5876/3750:tsid=30842:AllocBw=38453:BwList=14634/12500/5761/5557:tsid=30843:AllocBw=37105:BwList=15000/15000/3750/3355:tsid=30844:AllocBw=38295:BwList=14706/12339/3750/3750/3750:tsid=30845:AllocBw=25601:BwList=5762/12339/3750/3750:tsid=30846:AllocBw=38455:BwList=15000/12136/5761/5557:tsid=30847:AllocBw=26974:BwList=14634/12339:tsid=30848:AllocBw=29634:BwList=14634/15000:tsid=30849:AllocBw=37338:BwList=14838/15000/3750/3750:tsid=60958:AllocBw=36898:BwList=12339/12500/6501/5557:tsid=60959:AllocBw=37178:BwList=12339/12500/12339:tsid=60960:AllocBw=27339:BwList=12339/15000:tsid=60962:AllocBw=34839:BwList=12339/3750/15000/3750:tsid=60963:AllocBw=37500:BwList=15000/15000/3750/3750:tsid=60964:AllocBw=38346:BwList=15000/3754/15000/4592:tsid=60965:AllocBw=24626:BwList=15000/5876/3750:tsid=60966:AllocBw=34513:BwList=12502/12500/5761/3750
```

I need to grab all of `"AllocBW=######"` fields, separate the number part from the `"AllocBW"`, add them all together then subtract them from a set value.

In perl, I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Data::Dumper;
#
#
my $file = "/home/nick/perl/svcgroup.txt";
my @asplit;
my $c = 0;
open (FILE, "<", $file) or die "Can't open file".$!."\n";

while (<FILE>) {
        $_ =~ s/\n//g;
        push(@asplit, split (":", $_));
        #print Dumper @asplit;

}

foreach $splits (@asplit) {
        if ($splits =~ m/AllocBw/) {
        print $splits."\n";
        }
}
#print Dumper @asplit;
print "\n\n";
close FILE;
exit;
```

Which leaves me with:

```
AllocBw=38332
AllocBw=38750
AllocBw=36717
AllocBw=37011
AllocBw=38450
AllocBw=37460
AllocBw=31975
AllocBw=24260
AllocBw=38453
AllocBw=37105
AllocBw=38295
AllocBw=25601
AllocBw=38455
AllocBw=26974
AllocBw=29634
AllocBw=37338
AllocBw=36898
AllocBw=37178
AllocBw=27339
AllocBw=34839
AllocBw=37500
AllocBw=38346
AllocBw=24626
AllocBw=34513
```

This is where I get stuck. I'm not sure how to strip these values down to the number and add them up.

If someone can assist, I'd be grateful.  If this is more easily accomplished using something other than Perl, that's fine too.  My programming scope is limited, as I only make small scripts to accomplish small repetitive tasks at work.

**EDIT FOR BORODIN**

ie (not formatted like this, this is just for illustration):

```
AllocBw 12575+
AllocBw 12568+
AllocBw 12358 = TotAllocBw 37501

MaxBw 38800*3=116400

116400(MaxBw) - 37501(TotAllocBw) = TotAvaiBw 78899
```

This would just be a big bonus. The script you wrote works perfectly well for my purposes and I can adapt it as I need.  Thanks again! Much appreciated.  I was able to follow everything you did differently in the script and learned some new stuff.. Thanks for that as well.

Comment: You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` (in preference to the `-w` shebang line switch). There is otherwise little point in using `my` to declare your variables, which you should do as close as possible to their first point of use, and not all together in a block at the top of the program. It is also best practice to use lexical file handles instead of global ones, so `$file` instead of `FILE`, or even better `$fh` for File Handle

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I usually do use strict, but I forgot it in this one.  You've been a really big help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simplest to use a global regular expression match to find all occurrences of `AllocBw=...` in each line of your input file.

This program's outer `while` loop iterates over all the lines in the input file, and so should be executed only once.

The inner `while` iterates over all instances of the regex pattern `AllocBw=(\d+)` (`AllocBw=` followed by any number of decimal digits) and captures the numeric value into `$1`.

The captured number is added to `$total` each time, and can simply be printed at the end.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = '/home/nick/perl/svcgroup.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};

my $total = 0;

while ( <$fh> ) {
  $total += $1 while /AllocBw=(\d+)/g;
}

printf "Total: %d\n", $total;
```

**output**

```
Total: 826049
```